# How to move small png outside my element to achieve this?

Tags: image, wordpress, positioning, caption

how can I achieve something similar?

[image: that's the way I want it to look]

Basically, the question is: how can I position the small png with the corner from top left of the caption to be outside and to achieve this effect?

I am doing this to loop the latest category posts:

```
  <div class="pages-thumbs">
  <?php $cat_id = 19; $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat_id ); ?>
  <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
  <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Then, this is what I have for the h2 (css) in order to have that badge thing aligned to the top left:

```
.home-thumbs h2 {
    background: url("images/top-left-label.png") no-repeat scroll left top #CBCBCB;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -66px;
    max-width: 268px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is how it is now based on the css I have:
[image: this is how it looks now]

Should I try another approach as I don't seem to be able to move the bg png outside my h2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the background image to just the corner. Then edit your css as follows:

```
.home-thumbs h2 {
    background: url("images/top-left-label.png") no-repeat scroll left top;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -66px;
    max-width: 268px;
    position: absolute;
}

    .home-thumbs h2 span {

        width: inherit;
        background-color: #CBCBCB;
        padding-left: 12px;
        margin-top: HEIGHT OF H2 BG IMAGE;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't worked as you mentioned but I do understand how should I do it now and I was able to write it again and I have it working.